# Let ideal $I$ be generated by polynomial $p(x)$ in the ring $F[x]$ F-field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let ideal $I$ be generated by polynomial $p(x)$ in the ring $F[x]$ F-field. Prove: that the polynomials f(x), g(x) are in the same factor class of the ring $\implies f(x)=g(x)(mod\ p(x))$

$$f(x)+I=g(x)+I$$ (same factor class, i hope that makes it more clear, because i couldn't find the direct English translation)
$$g(x)=g_1(x)p(x)+r_1(x)$$
$$f(x)=g_2(x)p(x)+ r_2(x)$$
$$g_1(x)p(x)+r_1(x)+I=g_2(x)p(x)+ r_2(x)+I$$
$$**r_1(x)+I=r_2(x)+I**$$
$deg(r_1)<deg(p);deg(r_1)<deg(p)$
$$**r_1(x)-r_2(x)\in I** \implies r_1(x)-r_2(x)=q(x)p(x)$$
$$deg(r_1(x)-r_2(x))<deg(p(x))\implies g(x)=0;$$
$$\implies r_1(x)=r_2(x);$$

I highlighted what is unclear to me in between the stars..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p(x)\in I$, it follows that $g_1(x)p(x)\in I$ and $g_2(x)p(x)\in I$. Therefore $g_1(x)p(x) + r_1(x) + I = I + r_1(x) + I = r_1(x) + I$ and similarly for the other subscript. So $r_1(x)+I = r_2(x)+I$.

To get to the next equality, think about what the equality above means. It means that for some $i_1, i_2\in I$ that $r_1(x) + i_1 = r_2(x) + i_2$, so that $r_1(x) - r_2(x) = i_2-i_1\in I$.

Comment: thanks a lot, seems very simple when put like that. Do you have an explanation for:  $deg(r_1(x)-r_2(x))<deg(p(x))\implies g(x)=0;$

Comment: That is a typo. $deg(r_1(x)-r_2(x)) < deg(p(x))$ implies that $q(x) = 0$ (since $r_1(x)-r_2(x)=q(x)p(x)$). Thus $r_1(x) = r_2(x)$. If this answer satisfies your needs, I'd appreciate an upvote and an accept.